# Magento Accessing Invoice Attributes After Order Placed

Tags: magento

I am using the event `sales_order_save_after` to try and access the invoice sub total and do something with it.

In my observer.php I have:

```
public function peterParker($observer)
    {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

    $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('order_id', array('eq'=>$order->getId()));
    $orders->getSelect()->limit(1);

    $subTotal = $orders->getSubotal();

    Mage::log($subTotal);

}
```

But when I place an order I get this error in my php logs:

Call to undefined method Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Invoice_Collection::getSubotal()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty straight forward error message there

> Call to undefined method Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Invoice_Collection::getSubotal()

You're calling `getSubotal` on the collection object.  The collection object has no much method, and collections don't have magic getters or setters.

You'll want to pop the first item off that collection

```
$order = $orders->getFirstItem();
```

and then grab the data from that first item

```
Mage::Log($order->getData());
Mage::Log($order->getSubTotal());
```

Comment: Great thanks, it was getting the invoice from the collection that had me stumped.  Strangely the event seems to be firing twice as I got two entries in the log.

Comment: @MatthewDolman Collections are also `foreach`able.  Just do `<?php foreach($orders as $order){var_dump($order->getData()};` in the future.